# Is there a Windows 7/8/8.1 like automatic window sizer?

Tags: macos, windows

so I got a Macbook Pro a few months ago to use for coding and as a DAW. Really the only thing I miss about Windows 8.1 is the ability to drag a window to the upper left or upper right corner and have it automatically resized to take up the half the screen. Is there an option in Yosemite like this, or a tool I can download? Found it to be a real time saver as opposed to fiddling with height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next major version of OS X, 10.11 "El Capitan", will include such functionality. If you can't wait until then, there are several third party products, e.g. [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/), [Divvy](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33950/divvy), [Breeze](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33941/breeze), but you'll likely find others as well. An alternative might be [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt), a free tool, but it works with keyboard short cuts instead of dragging a window with the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net) has one of the features u are looking for.

You can find it in Window Snapping Settings:

[image: Window Snapping Settings in Better Touch Tool]